# Jayway jsonpath is returing value in floating-point format. How to get its original number format in String using java or scala?

Tags: java, scala, jsonpath

I am using jayway `JsonPath`, Suppose I have `Json` like this:
jsonObject:

```
{ 
"balance": 50000000000000.0
}

jspath: $.balance


 val response =JsonPath.parse(jsonObject).read(jsPath).toString
println("response: ", response )
```

here I am getting value as `"response: 5.0E7"` but I want it as `"50000000000000.0"`

I know how to convert from double to string. But my case is I have to call external Rest API and I will get json as response, based on jspath it has to fetch original value. It means the same code has to work for string, integer and double types with its original content, but not to its specific content format.

```
{ 
"balance": "50000000000000.0" (here balance is string)
}
expected: 50000000000000.0 result: 50000000000000.0

{ 
"balance": 50000000000000.00 (here balance is double)
}
expected: 50000000000000.0 result: 5.0E7(but I need 50000000000000.0)
```

The same code it has to work for both scenarios or is there any other library to get this solution or is there any chance of getting return type from read(), so using exception handling I can handle that.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 1):

Since you use Scala you can simply read value as `Any` and format it using pattern matching, e.g.:

```
val response: Any = JsonPath.parse(jsonObject).read(jsPath)
val formattedResponse = response match {
  case d: Double => d.formatted("%f")
  case _ => response.toString
}
```

Alternatively you can configure Jayway JsonPath to always parse floating numbers as `BigDecimal`, whose `toString` in most cases will print value without exponents (unless it's really small fraction (~ <1e-6), which anyway would be more readable with exponent) and has additional advantage of being capable of storing longer numbers without losing precision. This would however require configuring JsonPath with [JsonProvider](https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath#jsonprovider-spi) that always uses `BigDecimal` (default SmartJson can't do that, Jackson will work fine).

Comment: Thank you kstrek.